ERROR in Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename index.html
Actual issue:

While running the vue.config.js configuration, the following issue
occurred: ERROR in Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename index.html
While checking the dist folder:
dist_dev
static
home
  index.html
index.html


dist_dev/index.html :- loads fine as per the chunk configuration from pages/index in vue.config.js.
dist_dev/home/index.html :- is not rendered correctly using the chunk configuration of pages/home in vue.config.js. The issue is described below:
dist_dev/home/index.html:

Html Webpack Plugin:
<pre>
  ReferenceError: VUE_APP_CDN_ENVIRONMENT_URL is not defined

 - loader.js:12 eval
    [home.html?.]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/loader.js:12:11

 - loader.js:15 module.exports
    [home.html?.]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/loader.js:15:3

 - index.js:612 
    [employee-details]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:612:16

 - async Promise.all

</pre>


I tried to implement CSP Policy within vue.config.js plugins using html-webpack-plugin and strict-csp-html-webpack-plugin.
My project is a combination of Vue 3 and webpack build project.
Multiple page entries are set up within the pages configuration in vue.config.js.
Here, I'm sharing my environment details, vue.config.js and source folder path.

Environment:

Vue Version: 3.3.2
Element Plus Version: 2.3.4
Browser / OS: Chrome
Build: vue-cli-service build (webpack5)

vue.config.js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const StrictCSPHTMLWebpackPlugin = require('strict-csp-html-webpack-plugin')
const configureWebpack = {
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      os: false,
      path: false,
      fs: false,
      crypto: false,
      buffer: false,
      url: false
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
    new StrictCSPHTMLWebpackPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, {
      enabled: true,
      enableTrustedTypes: false,
      enableUnsafeEval: true,
      hashScript: true,
      hashStyle: true
    })
  ]
}

if (process.env.VUE_APP_ENV === 'Prod') {
  configureWebpack.devtool = 'hidden-source-map'
}
module.exports = defineConfig({
  configureWebpack: configureWebpack,
  lintOnSave: true,
  assetsDir: 'static',
  outputDir:
    process.env.VUE_APP_ENV === 'Prod'
      ? 'dist_prod'
      : 'dist_dev',
  productionSourceMap: false,
  chainWebpack: config => {
    const IS_VENDOR = /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/
    config.optimization.splitChunks({
      cacheGroups: {
        index: {
          name: 'chunk-index-vendors',
          priority: -11,
          chunks: chunk => chunk.name === 'index',
          test: IS_VENDOR,
          enforce: true
        },
        home: {
          name: 'chunk-track-vendors',
          priority: -11,
          chunks: chunk => chunk.name === 'home',
          test: IS_VENDOR,
          enforce: true
        },
        common: {
          name: 'chunk-common',
          priority: -20,
          chunks: 'initial',
          minChunks: 2,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
          enforce: true
        }
      }
    })
  },
  pages: {
    index: {
      entry: 'src/pages/index/main.js',
      template: 'public/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html',
      chunks: ['chunk-common', 'chunk-index-vendors', 'index']
    },
    home: {
      entry: 'src/pages/home/main.js',
      template: 'public/home.html',
      filename: 'home/index.html',
      chunks: ['chunk-common', 'chunk-home-vendors', 'home']
    }
  },
  publicPath: '/',
  runtimeCompiler: false
})

Source Files Path:
public
  static
    fonts
    js
    img
  index.html
  home.html
src
  assets
  router
    index.js
    homeRouter.js
  pages
    index
      App.vue
      main.js
    home
      App.vue
      main.js
  views
    pages.vue
    page.vue



How can I solve these issues and run the project with CSP policy with multiple entries?
